# 1 multidimensional array with 2 arrays inside merge the values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a dynamically created multidimensional array with 2 arrays inside, but note it could also be 4 arrays inside. depends on the user.
The problem is that i dont know how to merge the values into 1 array because i only have 1 multidimensional array, i looked into `array_merge` but that requires 2 arrays. Please point me in the right direction.

it looks like this:

```
array (size=2)
  'standaard' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => float 0.42
      1 => float 0.74
      2 => float 0.39
      3 => float 0.44
  'natugro' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => float 0.44
      1 => float 0.8
      2 => float 0.33
      3 => float 0.36
```

What i want is to merge the 2 arrays values togetter in 1 array seperated with ':'

Like this:

```
array (size=1)
     array (size=4)
       0 => string '0.42:0.44' (length=4)
       1 => string '0.74:0.8' (length=4)
       2 => string '0.39:0.33' (length=4)
       3 => string '0.44:0.36' (length=4)
```

What i tried:
but this only returns 1 array with the last values.

```
$test = array_merge($fruitHarvest);
var_dump($test);
```

This is the code that created the array.

```
$dbKenmerk = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT kenmerk FROM kenmerken WHERE user_id = '.$user.' AND jaar = '.$_SESSION["jaar"].'');
    while($getKenmerk = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbKenmerk)){

        $dbFruitHarvest = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT vruchten_geoogst FROM gewasregistratie WHERE user_id = '.$user.' AND jaar = '.$_SESSION["jaar"].' AND kenmerk = "'.$getKenmerk["kenmerk"].'"');

        foreach($dbFruitHarvest as $key => $innArr){
            foreach($innArr as $val){
                $fruitHarvest[$getKenmerk["kenmerk"]][] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($fruitHarvest);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just implode your elements with a colon.

```
<?php

    array_unshift($fruitHarvest, function(){return implode(":", func_get_args());});
    $result = call_user_func_array("array_map", $fruitHarvest);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: cool. but i will understand if  more easy answer be accepted :)

Comment: Seems this works great ! could you please explain a liitle bit what your doing here. i try understand it but i dont get the part with func_get_args()

Comment: @Julez You  basically call `array_map()` like this: `array_map(function(){return implode(":", func_Get_args());}, $fruitHarvest[subArray1], $fruitHarvest[subArray2], ...);` Which then means go through the first element of each sub array, then the second and so on

Comment: Okey thank you very much, i spended to many hours on this already... but i learned something new now.